# When is the hypergeometric function ever needed if it can be computed so much more efficiently?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

So I recently tried to compute some probabilities, and through my journey learned all about the hypergeometric distribution. I finally learned how to calculate the probability of having at least one red and at least one black ball in a draw of $4$ balls out of an urn filled with $4$ red, $4$ black and $52$ white balls.

$$\sum_{r=1}^4 \sum_{b=1}^4 \frac{\displaystyle{4 \choose r}{4 \choose b}{52 \choose 7-r-b}}{\displaystyle{60 \choose 7}}$$

But then someone pointed out to me that this probability can be computed much more efficiently $($obviously **after** I finally figured out how to implement the above in my preferred programming language$)$, like this:

$$1-2~\frac{\displaystyle\binom{56}{7}}{\displaystyle\binom{60}{7}}+\frac{\displaystyle\binom{52}{7}}{\displaystyle\binom{60}{7}}$$

So, I am wondering, why or when would I ever prefer to compute the actual probability $($hypergeometric function$)$ instead of trying to compute the probability of the event$($s$)$ **not** happening, and simply subtract from $1$.

Comment: For clearer illustration, consider a binomial variable $X$ with $n=100$. To compute $P(X \geq 1)$ it is indeed easier to just compute $1-P(X=0)$. But what about $P(X \geq 60)$? In this case you have fewer terms to calculate by considering $\sum_{k=60}^{100} P(X=k)$ rather than $1-\sum_{k=0}^{59} P(X=k)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are **extremely narrow-focused !** Look, you have basically discovered the following identity:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty{a \choose n}{b \choose k}{c \choose s-n-k}={a+b+c \choose s}+{c \choose s}-{a+c \choose s}-{b+c \choose s},$$

where $s=a+b-1$. Now, obviously, this is not “computationally efficient” for whatever

“real-life application” you can currently think of $($because, you know, that's what math is

**really** all about: computational efficiency, and real-life applications $\ldots)$ And indeed, giving

positive integer values to *a, b, c* is very “combinatoricky”, and very “probabilistic”, and very...

dull, boring, not to mention completely uninteresting... Now, if you really want to **impress**

**the girls**, you have to write one of those weird $\pi$ series, that leaves anyone and everyone

simply awe-struck... $~$ “*And just how exactly are we going to do that ?*”, you might ask. Well,

by giving fractional values to our three parameters. Try, for instance, $a=b=\dfrac12$ , and $c\in\mathbb N$.

You will end up with some **pretty cool** infinite series expressions for numbers of the form

$p+\dfrac q\pi$ , where $p,q\in\mathbb Q.~$ For instance, using the fact that $\displaystyle{1/2\choose n}=-\frac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}{(-4)^n(2n-1)}~,~$ we

arrive at $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg[\frac1{4^n(2n-1)}{2n\choose n}\bigg]^2=\frac4\pi$ . Computationally efficient ? Heck, no ! Impressive ?

Hell, yes ! ;-$)$

Comment: This answer is truly one of a kind